# Elmah doesn't work for my asp mvc site (returns 403: Forbidden)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

Elmah works just fine on my dev-machine, but when I deploy my asp mvc site to the server, I can't access http:///Elmah. The page itself works fine.

This is my Elmah configuration in web.config:

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
  <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
</sectionGroup>

....

<appSettings>
  ....
  <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
  <add key="AppName" value="ContactDatabase" />
</appSettings>

....

<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
</httpModules>

....

<modules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>

....

<elmah>
  <security allowRemoteAccess="yes"/>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" size="500" logPath="~/App_Data" />
</elmah>
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Try to access after base url like `mysite.com/elmah` .

Comment: I just deployed a new website with your config to an azure website. Everything works as it should there.

Comment: @ThomasArdal: As I said, it works on Dev, so it can't be completely wrong. There must be a more subtle error in the config or on IIS...